# Can I call focusGained() within the focusLost() in a Date Validator Program?

Tags: java, swing, date, netbeans

Please let me know if this is ok or not.

```
catch (ParseException ex) {
            jMessage.setText("Invalid Date. Input Date as DD/MM/YYYY");
            //For Clearing Text Field On Click:
            jDobTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    jMessage.setText("");
                }
                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    focusGained(e);
                }
            });
        }
```

I am trying to add a dateValidator in my jFrame. My question is can I call the method focusGained(e) within the focusLost(), to restart the whole process, every time wrong date is inserted and jTextField is clicked?

Btw that focusLost() was generated by netbeans. I have just added the focusGained().

Comment: See also [*Validating Input*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).

Comment: Pointless adding a `FocusListener` in the `Exception` handler